# Local sequence Error

Tags: c#, linq

The following is my query:

```
var query = (from m in db.Messages
             where txtSearch.Text.Split(' ').All(k => m.MessageText.Contains(k))
             select m.Id);
```

But, I get the following exception:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query
>   operators except the Contains() operator.

Comment: So, what is your question? The error message is right.

Comment: The question is that how can I find an alternative for this query to be run without error?